# prolog sets, stack overflow

Tags: prolog, algebra

I'm gonna show some code and ask, what could be optimized and where am I sucked?

```
sublist([], []).
sublist([H | Tail1], [H | Tail2]) :-
    sublist(Tail1, Tail2).
sublist(H, [_ | Tail]) :-
    sublist(H, Tail).

less(X, X, _).
less(X, Z, RelationList) :-
    member([X,Z], RelationList).
less(X, Z, RelationList) :-
    member([X,Y], RelationList),
    less(Y, Z, RelationList),
    \+less(Z, X, RelationList).

lessList(X, LessList, RelationList) :-
    findall(Y, less(X, Y, RelationList), List),
    list_to_set(List, L),
    sort(L, LessList), !.

list_mltpl(List1, List2, List) :-
    findall(X, (
        member(X, List1),
        member(X, List2)),
    List).

chain([_], _).
chain([H,T | Tail], RelationList) :-
    less(H, T, RelationList),
    chain([T|Tail], RelationList),
    !.

have_inf(X1, X2, RelationList) :-
    lessList(X1, X1_cone, RelationList),
    lessList(X2, X2_cone, RelationList),
    list_mltpl(X1_cone, X2_cone, Cone),
    chain(Cone, RelationList),
    !.

relations(List, E) :-
    findall([X1,X2],
        (member(X1, E),
        member(X2, E),
        X1 =\= X2),
    Relations),
    sublist(List, Relations).

semilattice(List, E) :-
    forall(
        (member(X1, E),
        member(X2, E),
        X1 < X2),
    have_inf(X1, X2, List)
    ).

main(E) :-
    relations(X, E),
    semilattice(X, E).
```

I'm trying to model all possible graph sets of N elements.
Predicate relations(List, E) connects list of possible graphs(List) and input set E.
Then I'm describing [semilattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) predicate to check relations' List for some properties.

So, what I have.

1) semilattice/2 is working fast and clear

```
?- semilattice([[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5]],[1,2,3,4,5]).
true.

?- semilattice([[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5]],[1,2,3,4,5]).
false.
```

2) relations/2 is working not well

```
?- findall(X, relations(X,[1,2,3,4]), List), length(List, Len), writeln(Len),fail.
4096
false.

?- findall(X, relations(X,[1,2,3,4,5]), List), length(List, Len), writeln(Len),fail.
ERROR: Out of global stack
^  Exception: (11) setup_call_catcher_cleanup('$bags':'$new_findall_bag'(17852886), '$bags':fa_loop(_G263, user:relations(_G263, [1, 2, 3, 4|...]), 17852886, _G268, []), _G835, '$bags':'$destroy_findall_bag'(17852886)) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

3) Mix of them to finding all possible semilattice does not work at all.

```
?- main([1,2]).
ERROR: Out of local stack
^  Exception: (15) setup_call_catcher_cleanup('$bags':'$new_findall_bag'(17852886), '$bags':fa_loop(_G41, user:less(1, _G41, [[1, 2], [2, 1]]), 17852886, _G52, []), _G4767764, '$bags':'$destroy_findall_bag'(17852886)) ?
```

Comment: Inefficient generation of all possible "relations" on a set of nodes is the root of your problems.  **sublist/2** will generate an exponential number of solutions and is not as written in tail recursive form, so it usses a lot of stack space.  The predicate **less/3** also seems inefficient and not in tail recursive form (but if I understand its purpose should be a deterministic predicate that lends itself to this optimization).  You talk about graphs on a set of N elements, but **relations/2** seems to aim at representing directed graphs (digraphs).  So a bit of clarification?

Comment: _>Inefficient generation of all possible "relations" on a set of nodes is the root of your problems._ 
If u know a best way to do this - tell me please

_>sublist/2 will generate an exponential number of solutions and is not as written in tail recursive form, so it usses a lot of stack space._
Yes, for n dots its 2^(n^2-n) sets

*less/3* is fine, it produced all relations with transitive property

_> relations/2 seems to aim at representing directed graphs_ 
Yes, it's what I want, cause it's binary relations problem

_>So a bit of clarification?_
Not at all, but thanx

Comment: Thanks, I meant the clarification was for me & you've provided it!

Comment: Maybe, the best solution is to divide this big problem to 2 small. First, generate all possible "relations" and write it to file. And second - read file and test each "relation" for "semilatticity". Certainly, if all that code is fastest as it could be

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only thing worse than posting an answer so late would have been to post an incorrect answer more quickly!  And I was about to do that several times.

You should be okay if you correct the last clause of **sublist/3**, so that the whole definition reads:

```
sublist([], []).
sublist([H | Tail1], [H | Tail2]) :-
    sublist(Tail1, Tail2).
sublist([_ | Tail1], Tail2) :-
    sublist(Tail1, Tail2).
```

As for writing things out to a file in the first pass and then reading it back in as a second pass, my guess is that would take more time.  Your **semilattice/2** predicate will knock out a lot of candidates.  So the situation is that dividing things up as you propose gives two big problems (because **relations/2** produces big output).

Perhaps an opportunity for improvement lies in reworking **relations/2** so that it produces fewer outputs, things that are more likely to be semilattices than a random subset of E x E minus the diagonal.  Scratching my head on that, but I don't have a concrete suggestion yet.